# WPF Binding DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to bound some properties from my DataContext to my DataGrid without success...
The DataGridComboBox is empty and invisible before clicking on it, and I have two rows instead of one for the following source code.

The XAML

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Classe" x:Name="Class_ClassName" Width="100" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ClassName, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Niveau">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="LevelTxt"  Width="50" TextChanged="LevelTxtTextChanged" Text="{Binding ClassLevel, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <Button x:Name="LevelUp"   Content="+" Width="15" Height="15" Click="LevelUpClick" FontSize="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
              <Button x:Name="LevelDown" Content="-" Width="15" Height="15" Click="LevelDownClick" FontSize="12" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataContext :

```
public class ClassRow
{
    public String ClassName;
    public int    ClassLevel;  
}

public class PJDataWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected List<ClassRow>  m_classRow;
    protected List<String>    m_classList;

    public PJDataWindow()
    {
        m_classRow   = new List<ClassRow>();
        m_classList  = new List<String>();

        //Test
        m_classList.Add("Classe1");
        m_classRow.Add(new ClassRow { ClassName = "Classe1", ClassLevel = 2 });

        OnPropertyChanged("ClassList");
        OnPropertyChanged("ClassRow");
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public List<ClassRow>  ClassRow
    {
        get
        {
            return m_classRow;
        }

        set
        {
            m_classRow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClassRow");
        }
    }

    public List<String> ClassList { get => m_classList; set { m_classList = value; OnPropertyChanged("ClassList"); } }
}
```

I am new in WPF and my search has led me to nowhere...

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems (so far).

The easiest problem is the two rows instead of one.  The extra row is the new item row.  Turn this off like so...

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="40" CanUserAddRows="False">
```

The next problem is the empty text field.  You can only bind to properties not fields.  So to fix this change the fields in the row object to properties.

```
public class ClassRow
{
    public String ClassName { get; set; }
    public int ClassLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Finally the reason the combo box is empty is that the items source is not bound to the data context.  The data grid column is outside the visual tree.  So it cannot find the source.  Fix it like this.

```
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="40" CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Classe" x:Name="Class_ClassName" Width="100" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ClassName, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, Path=DataContext.ClassList}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you it works like this. I didn't know that Properties and Public attributs aren't the same if the get and the set methods do not something special (accustomed to Python and I am new in C#). Thank you !